In SAS Enterprise Guide, can I avoid showing one specific sas dataset I created?
Can I write SAS code to run in e-Guide that creates a dataset, but does not show it in the Output Data tab (or does not show this tab)?
Context
I am writing a sasauto macro to send mails, for which I need to manage credential that expire after some time, so I keep them in a SAS table in WORK.
This dataset, of course, should be retained after the macro executed.
Ordinary users don't (have to) understand this data set, so having it popping up for them just confuses them.
Therefore my macro has to create a dataset, but should not show it to the users.
Other datasets created by the user of my macro should still be shown.

Where is it getting the credentials in the first place?  Why not just get them again when you need them?

In Enterprise Guide, you can change the Project and Process Flow setting "Maximum number of output datasets to add to the project" to 0. This will still create a note within the program, but no datasets will be shown in the output window.


If the datasets are not needed within the WORK directory once the macro completes, delete them at the end of the program:
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    delete dataset1 dataset2 dataset3;
quit;

This will prevent them from showing up in the project entirely.
But, since you need these datasets throughout the session, one other way could be to store the credentials as CSVs within WORK using temporary datasets. For example:
/* Save the credentials to a temporary CSV */
filename creds temp;

proc export 
    data=lib.credentials
    file=creds
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;

/* Read the CSV and do something with it */
data _null_;
    infile creds dlm=',' dsd;
    input username$ password$;
    call symputx('user', username);
    call symputx('pass', password);
run;


On your first suggestion:  I cannot in a macro change the settings in enterprise guide of another user. Further, if that user creates other datasets, he should find these like before.

On your second suggestion: I DO want to keep the data for subsequent calls to my macro.

Got it. One way would be to save the credentials to a temporary CSV instead, then read it later as needed. The CSV will be treated like a WORK dataset and deleted when the session ends. I updated my answer with this idea. I'm assuming the credentials are stored in some other dataset but if they aren't, you can adapt the code to fit how the credentials come in.

You can store you credential data in a catalog entry or temporary file.  You will not get anything 'popping up'
filename data catalog 'work.data.control.source' ;
data _null_ ;
  set sashelp.class ;
  file data delimiter=',' ;
  put name age sex height weight ;
run ;

You could also store the data in macro variables.
Either is not the best but a compromise when using EG as an application platform base instead of its more traditional analytic tool role.
Custom applications can use features in Excel add-in or SAS Integration Technologies.

It depends on HOW Enterprise Guide is guessing what datasets to include into the project.  I do not see any published documentation on how it works, so experiment and see.
Does it read the SAS log looking for notes about dataset creation?  Perhaps you just need to re-direct the log temporarily while creating the dataset.
filename xlog temp;
proc printto log=xlog; run;
data access_codes;
    .... make the dataset ....
run;
proc printto log=log; run;

Or perhaps put it into the same directory but make it using a different libref.
libname xwork ;
data xwork.access_codes;
    .... make the dataset ....
run;
libname xwork clear;

If that does not work the perhaps it is looking in the WORK directory for new files?  Try putting the file into a different directory.  You might still need to clear the library after making it to stop it from including it.
options DLCREATEDIR ;
libname xwork "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/xwork";
data xwork.access_codes;
    .... make the dataset ....
run;
libname xwork clear;


Using a different libref will not work, as also datasets created in permanent libraries do pop up. Redirecting the log will not work, either. You are just guessing?

Guessing? Yes. I don't run EG.  Try it.  I have seen discussion questions where removing the libref definition prevents the datasets from being opened. But perhaps that was SAS/Studio (a different front end tool for submitting SAS code).

Retaining the data in a file, like the other suggest, looks much safer to me.
